# Spamassassin: sa-update failed for unknown reasons, daily error, How to fix?

Tags: debian, spamassassin

For a while now I'm getting the following error-mail sent to my root account on my server. This is a fail occurring every time on the daily spamassassin update.

My setup followed the [Ars Technica Setup guide](http://arstechnica.com/business/2014/03/taking-e-mail-back-part-3-fortifying-your-box-against-spammers/2/) and I've already tried `chown`'ing the `/var/lib/spamassassin` by `spamd`. Even `spamd:debian-spamd` didn't help.

As for the OS I'm running Debian 8 Jessie and the newest spamassassin version.

So my question:
**How can I fix this error?**

**Error message:**

```
/etc/cron.daily/spamassassin:
error: unable to refresh mirrors file for channel updates.spamassassin.org, using old file
channel: could not find working mirror, channel failed
sa-update failed for unknown reasons
```

The results of `# sa-update -D -v` can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/3nYvWAr1), as they're too large for this question.

Comment: Run `sa-update -D -v` to get more verbosity and edit your question to include that output...

Comment: @masegaloeh, Done. Linked to pastebin as 100k chars aren't allowed here...

Comment: `sudo -u debian-spamd sa-update -D -v`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the execution of sa-update in you pastebin log was successful, I guess you we're running it as root.

Probably your directories `/var/lib/spamassassin/` and `/etc/spamassassin` and the files inside don't have the correct permissions. Try to chown it as the user sa-update is intended to run in the cronjob (for Ubuntu its `debian-spamd:debian-spamd` => `sudo chown -R debian-spamd:debian-spamd /etc/spamassassin /var/lib/spamassassin`).

Comment: Yes I ran it as root (indicated by the #). This doesn't work because the user `sa-update` seems not to exist. I tried `# chown -R u:g /var/lib/spamassassin` with `u` as `root` and `sa-update` and `g` as `root` and `sa-update`

Comment: I'll give `debian-spamd:debian-spamd` (available for me) a try for this night.

Comment: Just look in `/etc/cron.daily/spamassassin` and you'll find a line like `su - debian-spamd -c "sa-update --gpghomedir /var/lib/spamassassin/sa-update-keys"` - execute this for immediate testing :)

Comment: maybe I'm just blind, but I can't find such a line in my `/etc/cron.daily/spamassassin`... However running the given command gave no output.

Comment: can you paste you `/etc/cron.daily/spamassassin` somewhere?

Comment: [done](http://pastebin.com/uSpMBbdp).

Comment: ok, its this part `start-stop-daemon \
    --chuid debian-spamd:debian-spamd --start \
    --exec /usr/bin/sa-update -- \
    --gpghomedir /var/lib/spamassassin/sa-update-keys` which is equivalent to the line I've mentioned before - So if this runs without error, then everything seems to be nice...

Comment: I ran it and got no output (=good sign :) ). +1 for your answer and additional help and I'll accept it tomorrow when I see the job actually ran fine.

Comment: Tanks, hopefully its fixed :)

Comment: Well, thank you. The above problem is indeed fixed. However a new problem arose: `gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on homedir `/var/lib/spamassassin/sa-update-keys'`. Nonetheless, you fixed the original problem -> accepted.

Comment: `sa-update-keys` should be `700`

Comment: worked for the five days, but today I got the same mail that started the question... Do you recommend opening a new question? - Without the line `error: ...`